# Dynamic Inheritance Mapping in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

This is an inheritance mapping that works when the Types: Customer & Employee are known to me.

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .Map<Customer>(c => c.Requires("Type").HasValue("Customer"))
            .Map<Employee>(e => e.Requires("Type").HasValue("Employee"))
            .ToTable("People", "dbo");
```

In my case, the **Customer** and **Employee** classes will reside in plugin assemblies. So, I am trying to create the mapping using reflection.

**NOTE:** To keep the example simple I have hard coded the types. Also, I am only trying to create the mapping for the **Customer** type.

```cs
const BindingFlags binding = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;

EntityTypeConfiguration<Person> entityConfig = modelBuilder.Entity<Person>();
var entityConfigType = entityConfig.GetType();

// Map Method
MethodInfo mapMethod = null;
var methods = entityConfigType.GetMethods(binding);
foreach (var method in methods)
{
    if (method.Name == "Map" && method.IsGenericMethod)
    {
        mapMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Customer));
        break;
    }
}

// Requires Method
Type[] requiresArgType = new Type[]
    {
        typeof(string)
    };

var mappingConfigType = typeof(EntityMappingConfiguration<Customer>);
var requiresMethod = mappingConfigType.GetMethod("Requires", binding, null, requiresArgType, null);

// Has Value Method
var vccType = typeof (ValueConditionConfiguration);
Type[] hasValueArgType = new Type[]
    {
        typeof(string)
    };

var hasValueMethod = vccType.GetMethod("HasValue", binding, null, hasValueArgType, null);

var param1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof (EntityMappingConfiguration<Customer>), "c");
var requiresCall1 = Expression.Call(param1, requiresMethod, Expression.Constant("Type"));
var hasValueCall1 = Expression.Call(requiresCall1, hasValueMethod, Expression.Constant("Customer"));

var lambda1 = Expression.Lambda(hasValueCall1, param1);
var @delegate1 = lambda1.Compile();

mapMethod.Invoke(entityConfig, new object[]
    {
        @delegate1
    });
```

When trying to invoke the **Map** method, the following Exception is thrown:-

```
Object of type 'System.Func`2[System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.EntityMappingConfiguration`1[ConsoleApplication1.Customer],System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.StringColumnConfiguration]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Action`1[System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.EntityMappingConfiguration`1[ConsoleApplication1.Customer]]'.
```

How do I convert

```
Func<EntityMappingConfiguration<Customer>> with return type of StringColumnConfiguration
```

to

```
Action<EntityMappingConfiguration<Customer>>
```

Comment: The generic variant of the Lambda method did the trick.

Comment: Hi, would you mind elaborating this in an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted later? (Don't worry, this is common practice at StackOverflow).

Answer (score 0):

I replaced

```
var lambda1 = Expression.Lambda(hasValueCall1, param1);
```

with the following

```
MethodInfo[] expressionMethods = typeof (Expression).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

MethodInfo lambdaMethod = null;
foreach (MethodInfo method in expressionMethods)
{
    if (method.Name == "Lambda" && method.IsGenericMethod && method.GetParameters().Length == 2)
    {
        lambdaMethod = method;
        break;
    }
}

MethodInfo genericLambdaMethod = lambdaMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof (Action<>).MakeGenericType(typeof<EntityMappingConfiguration<Customer>>));

LambdaExpression lambda1 = (LambdaExpression) genericLambdaMethod.Invoke(null, new object[]
{
    hasValueCall1, new[]
    {
        param1
    }
});
```